# Show latest tweet with script without showing @replies

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, plugins, twitter

I'm using a script from http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/ to display a latest tweet on a website, code example 7 shows how I can use it to show tweets without displaying @replies, I tried this but it doesn't work. When I do it it just doesn't display anything.

Also how can I reorder it so that the tweet_time displays AFTER the tweet?

Thank you!

Code that works fine which just displays latest tweet:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function($){
    $(".tweet").tweet({
        username: "fearofmobs",
        join_text: "auto",
        count: 1,
        auto_join_text_default: "", 
        auto_join_text_ed: "we",
        auto_join_text_ing: "we were",
        auto_join_text_reply: "we replied to",
        auto_join_text_url: "we were checking out",
        loading_text: "loading tweets..."
    });
});
```

Code that I want to use which should omit @replies, but just displays nothing:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function($){
    $("#filter").tweet({
      count: 1,
      fetch: 20,
      filter: function(t){ return ! /^@\w+/.test(t.tweet_raw_text); },
      username: "fearofmobs"
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This jsFiddle looks like what you want -- did I get it right?](http://jsfiddle.net/hBF2x/1/)

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(".tweet").tweet({
    username: "fearofmobs",
    join_text: "auto",
    count: 20,
    auto_join_text_default: "",
    auto_join_text_ed: "we",
    auto_join_text_ing: "we were",
    auto_join_text_reply: "we replied to",
    auto_join_text_url: "we were checking out",
    loading_text: "loading tweets...",
    fetch: 20,
    filter: function(t){ return ! /^@\w+/.test(t.tweet_raw_text); }
  });
});
```

Comment: So helpful, thank you! Do you know how to move the tweet_time to show after the tweet too?

Comment: `template: '{text} >> {time}'` Add this after the `filter:` method (make sure to use a `comma` after the closing `}` on the `filter:` line.